# Define a function to be equal to the numerical solution of a PDE

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation, assignment

I am curious about if it is possible to define a function to be equal to the numerical solution of a PDE (got by `NDSolve`)? I know that when we try to plot the solution, we can achieve that by, say

```
solution = NDSolve[ PDEs, { x, ... }, { y, ... } ];

Plot3D[Evaluate[f[x, y] /. solution], {x, ...}, {y, ...}]
```

but I wonder if it is possible to define a function (say, `g[x, y`]) to be equal to `solution`. I have tried

```
 g[x_, y_] = f[x, y] /. solution;
```

but it does not work, I always get results like

> ```
>  Interpolition[...]
> ```

Comment: Why do you thinik it does not work? Just try e.g. `g[1, 1]`. For more information check the document of `InterpolatingFunction` carefully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of a PDE:

```
 Clear[u];
\[CapitalOmega] = 
  DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[True, {{x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 30}}]];
Module[{
  op = 1400*(D[T[x, y], {x, 2}] + D[T[x, y], {y, 2}]),
  G = NeumannValue[-6.71*(T[x, y] - 295), 2 <= y <= 28 && x == 5] + 
    NeumannValue[60, 7 <= y <= 23 && x == 0]},
 u = NDSolveValue[{op == G}, T, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]]]

   (*  InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 5.}, {0., 30.}}, <>]  *)
```

Now you can define a function

```
vv[x_, y_] := u[x, y]
```

Let us, for example, plot it:

```
 Plot3D[vv[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: If you have `u = NDSolveValue...` why use `vv`? BTW, it's useful to always solve as `(N)DSolve(Value)[PDEs, f, domain]` and not `[PDES, f[vars], domain]`. You are using the former, of course, but I think it's not been stressed enough.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP You are right, it is not necessary. However, OP (for whatever reason) wanted to have a function defined in a standard way. The point is that it is no straighforwardly defined. Here I show the workaround.  Concerning your second statement, sometimes this is useful, sometimes that. It depends on what you do next. In general there is no much difference.

Comment: I think it's particularly useful when delayed assignments are used, e.g. worst case scenario `f[x_] := Interpolation[data][x]` will perform much slower than `f = Interpolation[data]`

Comment: I see, one can use 
sol = NDSolveValue[ ... ]; f[ x_, y_ ] := sol[ x, y ]; or sol = NDSolve[ ... ]; then f[ x_, y_ ] := ( T/.sol)[[ 1 ]]. Both give the correct result! thanks!